# I have a batch file in my project which is giving error - please hellp

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, batch-file

```
set SolutionDir=D:\CWL\Source\Libs\SharpSSH
set keyfile=%SolutionDir%\SharpSSH\SharpSsh_KeyFile.snk
set indll=%SolutionDir%\bin\Release\Tamir.SharpSSH.dll
set indll1=%SolutionDir%\bin\Release\Org.Mentalis.Security.dll
set indll2=%SolutionDir%\bin\Release\DiffieHellman.dll
set outdir=%SolutionDir%\..
set outdll=%outdir%\Tamir.SharpSSH.dll
echo.
echo.  Creating Merged Assembly: %outdll%
echo.
C:\nor-devops\projects\nor_cwl_manager\Source\BuildTools\ILMerge.exe \t:dll /ndebug /targetplatform:2,C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727 /keyfile:%keyfile% /out:%outdll% %indll% %indll1% %indll2%
```

this is what I have in my VS2015 project Bulid events: 
`if not "$(ConfigurationName)"=="Release" goto skip`
`call "$(ProjectDir)..\PostBuildSharpSSH_ILMerge.bat"`
`:skip`

Error: "The command "if not "Release"=="Release" goto skip :skip" exited with code 1.

I don't understand what is going wrong it used to work fine.

Comment: ***W H A T*** error does this batch file cause?!?!?!!? You need to **TELL US** - we cannot see your screen, nor read your mind ....

Comment: What operating System?  Make sure the exe file exits.  I would open up a cmd.exe window and change directories to BuildTools.  Then type ILMerge.exe.  See if application opens and the error you get.  It will help isolate where the error is located.

Comment: Updated the Question.  jdweng Exe works fine and correct path given as well

Comment: My operating system is Win 8.1 64 bit

Comment: can you execute the batch from command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bit hard to tell with the formatting you have. Presumably you have 3 lines rather than 1 as is shown. In any case you can simplify and get rid of the goto with this:

```
if "$(ConfigurationName)"=="Release" call "$(ProjectDir)..\PostBuildSharpSSH_ILMerge.bat"
```

Are you executing builds locally or submitting them to a build agent via a build controller? Check user permissions if executing on SAB machine (may be different user).